# "Can't provide internet" on network with internet

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

I own a Motorola Edge 20 Fusion running Android 12.

Sometimes when I connect to my home network, my phone says "Connected to device. Can't provide internet." and will disconnect after a few seconds. There is no prompt about staying connected to the network that normally appears.

Generally, the internet connection *does* work in the brief moments where it is connected, but obviously fails whenever it disconnects, meaning that the internet is not actually usable.

My home network does have internet, and I have not run into this issue on any other device, Android or not. My home network consists of an OpnSense router, with a number of OpenWRT-based access points.

So far I have tried:

- Rebooting my phone - generally does not help
- Rebooting my APs - sometimes this helps. I'm not convinced this actually fixes the issue, rather than being a coincidence though - other devices have no issues connecting to my network even when my phone does.
- Checking that http://google.com/generate_204 and http://gstatic.com/generate_204 are available on my network [as per this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/201439/wifi-status-connected-no-internet-can-access-all-internet-resources-ive-tes) - they are

I'm not sure how or where to look now with fixing this. I'd appreciate any help.